# Google Chart - Show static legend and remove percentage field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-api, google-visualization

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 
    function drawChart() {

    Year = ['Week 1','Week 2','Week 3','Week 4','Week 5'];
    Hours = [42,52,40,38,40];

    var dataArray = [['Week', 'Hours']];

    for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++){
       dataArray.push ([Year[n], Hours[n]])
    }

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);



        var options = {
        legend: {position: 'right'},
            is3D: 'true',
            width: 550,
            height: 350,
            colors: [<?php echo $color_code_string ;?>], //defines color '#00bcd4','#ff0000','#ff0000','#bdbdbd','#bdbdbd'
            pieSliceText: 'label',
            };  

          // redraw the chart.
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);

    }
</script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**Output**

[image]

1. How do I put fix legend as shown in image which mentions status viz.
   `Week not active`, `Not Submitted` instead of `Week 1`, `Week 2` ? I only need to change legend to custom titles, rest will be same,
2. Is it possible to remove only percentage field shown onhover and show text like `42 hours` ?
3. Also if I change from `Hours = [42,52,40,38,40] to Hours =
   [42,52,40,0,0]` , the pie shows only `3` sections instead of `5`.
   How can I show `5` sections with `0` value passed

Comment: I do not see any reason for downvote. Pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by customizing chart tooltip, for that purpose we need to introduce column with [tooltip role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles):

```
data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true} });
```

and then specify custom tooltip text, for example:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows();i++){
        var tooltipText = '...'; 
        data.setValue(i,2,tooltipText);
  }
```

**Complete example**

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var Year = ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5'];
    var Hours = [42, 52, 40, 38, 40];

    var dataArray = [['Week', 'Hours']];

    for (var n = 0; n < Hours.length; n++) {
        dataArray.push([Year[n], Hours[n]]);
    }

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true} });  
    
    var yearStatuses = {
        'Week 1': 'Week not active',
        'Week 2': 'Not Submitted'
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows();i++){
        var curYear = data.getValue(i,0);
        var yearStatus = (typeof yearStatuses[curYear] != 'undefined' ? yearStatuses[curYear] : ''); 
        var tooltipText =  yearStatus + '<br/>' + '<b>' + data.getValue(i,1) + ' hours</b>';
        data.setValue(i,2,tooltipText);
    }


    var options = {
        legend: { position: 'right' },
        is3D: 'true',
        width: 550,
        height: 350,
        colors: ['#00bcd4', '#ff0000', '#ff0000', '#bdbdbd', '#bdbdbd'],
        pieSliceText: 'label',
        //tooltip: {isHtml: true}
    };


    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**Update**

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var Year = ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5'];
    var Hours = [42, 52, 40, 38, 40];

    var dataArray = [['Week', 'Hours']];

    for (var n = 0; n < Hours.length; n++) {
        dataArray.push([Year[n], Hours[n]]);
    }

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true} });  
    for(var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows();i++){
        var curYear = data.getValue(i,0);
        var tooltipText = data.getValue(i,1) + ' hours</b>';
        data.setValue(i,2,tooltipText); 
    }


    var options = {
        legend: { position: 'right' },
        is3D: 'true',
        width: 550,
        height: 350,
        colors: ['#00bcd4', '#ff0000', '#ff0000', '#bdbdbd', '#bdbdbd'],
        pieSliceText: 'label'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    setLegendProperties(chart.getContainer());
}



function setLegendProperties(chart)
{
    var yearStatuses = {
        'Week 1': 'Week not active',
        'Week 2': 'Not Submitted',
        'Week 3': 'Submitted',
        'Week 4': 'Approved',
        'Week 5': 'Rejected'
    };

    var legendBar = document.getElementsByTagName('g')[0]; //get legend container  
    var labels = legendBar.getElementsByTagName('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var curLabel = labels[i].innerHTML;
        labels[i].innerHTML = yearStatuses[curLabel];
     }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**Update 2**

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var Year = ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6'];
    var Hours = [42, 52, 40, 38, 40, 50];

    var dataArray = [['Week', 'Hours']];

    for (var n = 0; n < Hours.length; n++) {
        dataArray.push([Year[n], Hours[n]]);
    }

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true} });  
    for(var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows();i++){
        var curYear = data.getValue(i,0);
        var tooltipText = data.getValue(i,1) + ' hours</b>';
        data.setValue(i,2,tooltipText); 
    }


    var options = {
        legend: { position: 'right' },
        is3D: 'true',
        width: 550,
        height: 350,
        colors: ['#00bcd4', '#ff0000', '#ff0000', '#bdbdbd', '#bdbdbd'],
        pieSliceText: 'label'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    setLegendProperties(chart.getContainer());
}



function setLegendProperties(chart)
{
    
    var legendBar = document.getElementsByTagName('g')[0]; //get legend container  


    var legendInfo = {
        'Week 1': {'Label': 'Week not active', 'IconColor': '#FFA500'},
        'Week 2': {'Label': 'Not Submitted', 'IconColor': '#bdbdbd'},
        'Week 3': {'Label':'Submitted', 'IconColor': '#00bcd4'} ,
        'Week 4': {'Label':'Approved', 'IconColor': '#00ff00'},
        'Week 5': {'Label':'Rejected', 'IconColor': '#ff0000'}
    };

    //adjust legend labels & icons
    var labels = legendBar.getElementsByTagName('text');
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var key = labels[i].innerHTML;
        labels[i].innerHTML = legendInfo[key].Label;

        var icon = labels[i].parentElement.nextSibling;
        icon.setAttribute('fill',legendInfo[key].IconColor);
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: The code works and answers my question#1. But for ques #2 how do I show static titles in legend and not onhover. Tolltip will only show `Week 1 40 hours` information. Also for ques #3, even if value is 0, can we show `5` sections instead of `3` ?

Comment: The output is still the same. Considering static legend titles display and onhover information

Comment: Have you tried the **updated** example? It displays custom legend titles and tooltips

Comment: Was checking old update.My bad. Well its pretty close but I have one query on how to just show `FIXED LEGENDS with COLORS` as stated in image ? Your snippet works but it  shows dynamic pie slice color.

Comment: The only difference I see is the legend color. Can we make it fix color for titles ? For ex: `Week not active` is `orange`. For `<circle cx="340" cy="73" r="6" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#00bcd4"/>`. Do we have to access `circle` property ?

Comment: It could be something like this ` var colors = document.getElementsByTagName('circle');
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var curLabel = labels[i].innerHTML;
        var curColor = colors[i].attributes['fill'];
        console.log(colors[i].attributes['fill']);
        console.log(yearStatuses[curLabel]);
        labels[i].innerHTML = yearStatuses[curLabel];
 }`. But some how I am unable to replace fill colors with fix color value in the same you did for `yearStatuses`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy, see updated answer (example **No 2**)

Comment: The updated snippet works like a charm. Could not thank you more for your sincere efforts. I really appreciate.

Comment: If pie slice has 4 or 6 sections, the legend title counts to 4 or 6 as well. For ex: If `week 6` appears in pie, then legend shows sixth option as `week 6` instead of fix `5` status. How could I overcome it ? I guess the same will happen when pie has `4` slices. Because pie slices could `4/5/6` but legends titles are fix `5`

Comment: I have updated your snippet 2 by adding `week 6` and its hours. You can run the snippet to see the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90862/discussion-between-slimshadddyyy-and-vadim-gremyachev).

Comment: If i understood your question,  since `legendInfo` table that contains legend and tooltip info depends on input data, it of course should be updated.

Comment: Tooltip will contain dynamic data anyhow. But irrespective of pie slice count, the legend titles should be fixed. Can we just make it static ? Also if it has week 6, exception `TypeError: legendInfo[key] is undefined
labels[i].innerHTML = legendInfo[key].Label;`

Comment: Regarding fixing legend, you could just add the item to `legendInfo` table:  `'Week 6': {'Label':'--custom label goes here--', 'IconColor': '--icon color--'}`

Comment: Legend titles are mapped with week count viz, `'week 1': {'Label': 'Week not active', 'IconColor': '#ff9900'},`. But here the legend status are fix and does not depends on week count. So even if its week-6 or week-4 the legend titles would always remain same. We do not need to add one more legend title if the week count increases or decreases.

Comment: There is a strange issue of Legends not appearing as expected using `setLegendProperties` in Internet Explorer ? What could be causing IE to not display the static legend details ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `Year = ['Week 1','Week 2','Week 3','Week 4','Week 5'];` with your requested titles. Note that the corresponding position of values will be for that "title" in your `Hours` array.
2. You need to add the following to your options: `tooltip:{text:'value'}`

More info about piecharts [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart).

Comment: Replacing Year with Titles will also replace the pie char info. I just need to replace legend with static text or custom titles. Rest will remain same

Comment: I don't see the problem in that,  but you could try JSON formatting your data. Regarding question #3 please read the documentation from Google or provide what you've tried.